# SQL- Selecting Highest or Second Highest Entry based on condition

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, and got stuck on the below condition:
[Input and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xgmE.png)
If a group has 3 years, we will take max year -1,
If a group has 2 years, we will take max of the year

Can anyone please help me in this?

I tried generating the row_number() over (partition by "Group","Year"), but not able to understand how to make selection further.

Query Used till now

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by "Group","Year") as "RN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach -

```
WITH ranked_data AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group1 ORDER BY year1 DESC) AS rn,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY group1) AS row_count,
    MAX(year1) OVER (PARTITION BY group1) AS max_year
  FROM t1
)
SELECT
  group1,
  CASE
    WHEN row_count = 3 THEN max_year - 1
    WHEN row_count = 2 THEN max_year
  END AS selected_year
FROM ranked_data
WHERE rn = 1;
```

In this updated query, we added the `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY group1)` expression in the CTE to calculate the row count within each group. We then used this `row_count` value in the `CASE` expression to determine the selected year.

Now, when the row count is 3, it subtracts 1 from the maximum year (`max_year`) to get the selected year. When the row count is 2, it directly selects the maximum year.

[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/4-eFAJog)